# Disable the GIO network extension?

Tags: linux, thunar

I don't use any LAN, so the following "Network" is useless to me:

[image]

I checked the source code partially and it seems to be using the GIO network extension. How can I disable this without modification of the source code ?

Comment: When using the source, have a look at `./configure --help` which shows you some available flags; there might be some way to disable it.